# Substitute for the over clause in MySQL workbench 6.1 CE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Can this be implemented in mySql?
I want to add the forecast value for consecutive rows on ordering by ID, Date.

In Microsoft SQL, it can be done by:

```
Select 
  ID, Date, Forecast, 
  sum(forecast) 
    over (partition by ID 
          order by Date Rows between 1 following and 3 following) end as sum3 
  from sample_data
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sadly, window/analytic functions in MySQL are really awkward to emulate in an efficient way :-/

Comment: I basically need the sum of (say) next 6 rows in the first row, which I was able to implement in sql server by using the over clause. I need to reproduce the same thing in MySQL workbench 6.1 CE